# Numerical analysis: Subtraction of nearly equal numbers

Tags: numerical-methods, computer-science

I'm reading Numerical Analysis by Sauer. In the first chapter the book describes the Loss of Significance when a computer subtracts nearly equal number. In one of the exercises you are asked to identify for with values of $x$ there is a subtraction of nearly equal numbers, and find an alternate form that avoids the problem.

For the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{1}{1-x}$ it clearly has a loss of significance when $x\rightarrow 0$, which is the answer in the book with the alternate form $\frac{-2x}{1-x^2}$.

My question is why the function won't have loss of significance when $x\rightarrow 1$ or $x\rightarrow -1$? One of $\frac{1}{1+x}$,$\frac{1}{1-x}$ will blow up for any $x$ that is close enough to $1$ or $-1$ without being represented as exactly $1$ or $-1$ by the computer, else Inf would be the answer and I assume that is enough to discard the result and reevaluate the expression.

Comment: I suppose that for $x$ becoming close to $1$ or $-1$, the terms $\frac{1}{1+x}$ and $\frac{1}{1-x}$ are not *nearly equal* and so this case isn't relevant to what you are learning.

Comment: The loss you mention applies to one of the fractions. Dividing by a number near $0$ is numerically very unstable. This error of course occurs also in the difference because the other fraction is numerically stable.

Comment: suppose we look at x close to 1. Then wouldn't $\frac{1}{1-x}$ become a very large number with very poor significance?

Comment: A connected issue, in the framework of solving quadratic equations : https://pavpanchekha.com/blog/accurate-quadratic.html

Comment: No, as long as no overflow occurs the difference $1-x$ is exact and $1/(1-x)$ is also computed to the relative accuracy of the general division. This would be different if you have $x=1-u$ with $u$ going to zero. Then you lose increasingly more bits or digits from $u$ in $1-(1-u)$ compared to the exact value $u$.